# Is it possible to configure dedicated root user at mysql

Tags: mysql

I can't login with valid root user when there has "too many connection" error. Is it possible to configure root user with dedicated connection slot? So, whatever number of user connected the connection threshold will not apply at that dedicated user.

> ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections

Comment: Can you show the Complete error message please

Comment: This behaviour is actually the default, see [Too many connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/too-many-connections.html), there is always one reserved slot for a super user.

Comment: So to extrapolate from above. It would appear that you have given out the root user to more than one person instead of creating Admin accounts for them thus reserving the root user for emergency acces only

Comment: May one ask if your applications are using root as their login account perhaps?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, my application using different user

Comment: So how many people know the `root` account password?

Comment: no other except me